# Unable to remove hyperlink from dynamic generated HTML during export to excel

Tags: c#, .net, httpcontext

I want to remove hyperlink from dynamic generated HTML during Export to excel.
I tried lot by googling but still I could not find solution.
my code is

```
string CompanyName = string.Empty;
CompanyName = Session["CompanyName"].ToString();
CompanyName = CompanyName.Replace(" ", "_");
string FileName = CompanyName.Trim() + "-Weekly_CashFlow_Statement_" + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".xls";


HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader(
    "Content-Disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

this.Page.EnableViewState = false;
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
tblCashFlow.RenderControl(hw);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(tw.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Changed my code from

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(tw.ToString());

to 

 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Regex.Replace(tw.ToString(), "</?(a|A).*?>", ""));
```

and it works fine for me.
its solution of my question